# ASP.NET sub Application compilation error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, compilation

My application deploy as Sup-App in a big site, sometimes it got compilation error like this:

Exception information:

```
Exception type: HttpCompileException 
Exception message: (0): error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple  name 'App_GlobalResources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side.
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass32`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__30()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureFirstTimeDirectoryInit(VirtualPath virtualDir)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

May you please give me some guidance? what kind of this error and how to workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the bin folder on the target server before publishing and check... 
The only problem I could see is if the local bin directory contains newer versions of existing components.